# jQuery mouseover and mousleave causing flickers

Tags: jquery, html, css

My problem is `mouseover` and `mouseout`. As there some data which is dynamically generated in div `#mydiv` and also div with class `on-hover` is also generated dynamically .. so i must use `jQuery(document).on({ mouseenter:` for live event of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.. all going good.. but apparently mouseover is flicking like hell...

my html code :

```
    <a href="" >
    <div id="mydiv" class="image">
        <img src="http://core2.staticworld.net/images/article/2013/08/diy-app-dev-100050594-large.jpg" /> </div>
    <div  class="on-hover"> this is my hover text </div>
</a>
```

my js code :

```
jQuery(document).on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $("#mydiv").next(".on-hover").show();
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(".on-hover").hide();
    }
}, "#mydiv");
```

and my css :

```
.image{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.on-hover{
    font-size:2em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(222, 31, 57);
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Also I have same problem on [jsFeild](http://jsfiddle.net/hecoe9n1/).

Comment: Do you really need jquery for this.. you can try the same using CSS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `on-hover` div into `mydiv`. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/chamikasandamal/hecoe9n1/8/)**

```
<a href="">
    <div id="mydiv" class="image">
        <img src="http://core2.staticworld.net/images/article/2013/08/diy-app-dev-100050594-large.jpg" /> 
        <div class="on-hover"> this is my hover text </div>
    </div>    
</a>
```

JS,

```
jQuery(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(".on-hover").show();

    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(".on-hover").hide();
    }
}, "#mydiv");
```

**Update**

---

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hecoe9n1/11/) based on the comment

Comment: its seems working fine in your case 

can u please solve in this ?? http://jsfiddle.net/hecoe9n1/9/

Comment: I think you've got already an answer from either of the three.

Answer (score 2):

Why not remove the JS and simply do this in CSS, thereby clearly maintaining a separation of concerns (JS for functionality, CSS for presentation):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/hecoe9n1/6/)

```
.image {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.on-hover {
    font-size:2em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: none;
    background-color: rgb(222, 31, 57);
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

a:hover .on-hover {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: i have dynamic loaded content that is the problem like this http://jsfiddle.net/hecoe9n1/9/

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE:](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/hecoe9n1/7/)

What your are trying is possible with css only:

CSS :

```
.a-tag {
    display: block;
}
.on-hover {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: none;
    background-color: rgb(222, 31, 57);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0px;
}
.a-tag:hover .on-hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: css can not be implemented on dynamic loaded content like in this case http://jsfiddle.net/hecoe9n1/9/